# How can I make the selected row in a QML table view remain the same when changing the model

Tags: qt, qml, qtableview

I am using a qml table view to display a set of values.  On each row, there are buttons that allow the user to adjust the value.

My model is an array of qobjects.  Every time the user does something to change a value, I am sending a signal to my controller class, it is creating a new model and giving that to the table view.  Unfortunately, when you update the model, the selected row is set to -1.  Is there some way to change that behavior?

Comment: I don't think that you should make a new model every time the data changes.

Comment: As already said changing a model is not good idea. Anyway, if you still want to use this code you can store `TableView.currentRow` before changing the model and restore it after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should update the model, not change it entirely.

That said, your problem is that the currently selected row index (currentRow) changes, yes? If so, perhaps you should store the index in a variable, which you update like so:

```
TableView {
    ...
    property int unwaveringCurrentRow
    ...
    onCurrentRowChanged: { if (currentRow != -1) unwaveringCurrentRow = currentRow }
    ...

    onModelChanged: { currentRow = unwaveringCurrentRow }
}
```

Also, note how the current row is reset again, when the model changes.

Comment: That is more or less what I ended up doing.  The model change is more complicated than what I want to do in qml.

Comment: At the qml side all arrays are just javascript arrays, and you could use push and splice to modify them. I am not sure, whether the view supports modifying arrays. You could also use one of the existing models, they are very easy to use on the qml side. For example, here is a simplistic use of listmodel:
`ListView {
    model: ListModel { id: myModel }
    Component.onCompleted: { myModel.append(someObject) }
}`

Comment: @Scottfivefour -- forgot to add your nick for notification of my comment. And what I meant above was simplistic dynamic use of listmodel on the javascript side -- it is indeed pretty easy. I don't of course know everything you need to do and so on.